# Controlling the width of a directory listing in terminals

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

I'm on OS X with iTerm2 and OhMyZsh.

When I do an `ls` command, somehow it decides how much space it needs between the output columns. Is there a way to control that and tell it how many spaces to show between result columns?

I think it is easier to describe what I mean by some screen shots:

Notice the spacing between columns:

[image]

vs

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing of columns in `ls` is done automatically to fit as little rows as possible into the screen.

You can override this by setting the `COLUMNS` environment variable (see `man ls`), e.g. to test it, you can just run:

```
COLUMNS=30 ls
```

Of course you can set a fixed size for `COLUMNS` in your `~/.zshrc` – Bash users want `~/.bash_profile` instead:

```
export COLUMNS=30
```

Note that BSD `ls`, as used in OS X, is different from [GNU `ls`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html), which has a `--tabsize` option.

Comment: interesting. Ok I wanted to try it with a "COLUMNS=2 ls" and it breaks down each output in one separate row, not showing in column anymore.

Comment: It won't break a file name into two rows, so if `COLUMNS` is smaller than the amount of characters in the shortest file name, you'll just get a "normal" listing.

Comment: weird, hmm it actually did! I tried a "COLUMNS=100 ls" and if the name was larger for the last columns it outputted them on the next line..thanks very much for follow up.

Comment: maybe LS_COLWIDTHS instead?

Comment: This is only related to long `ls` listings (e.g. `ls -l`)